# what is the right syntax for node-redis PUBSUB CHANNELS

Tags: node.js, redis, node-redis

what is the right syntax for node-redis  PUBSUB CHANNELS

```
  await redis.sendCommand(('PUBSUB CHANNELS', []), function(err,result){
    console.log(err);
    console.log(result);
  });
```

I try like this but no message in console.
When I try redis-cli console its working but I dont find right syntax in nodejs.

node-redis github: https://github.com/redis/node-redis

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an example of how to use `PUBSUB CHANNELS` with node-redis 4.x:

index.js:

```
import { createClient } from 'redis';

const client = createClient();

await client.connect();

const activeChannels = await client.pubSubChannels();
console.log(activeChannels);

await client.quit();
```

package.json:

```
{
  "name": "nrpubsubchannels",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "redis": "^4.6.7"
  },
  "type": "module"
}
```

Subscribe to some channels in `redis-cli`:

```
$ redis-cli
127.0.0.1:6379> subscribe channel1 channel2
Reading messages... (press Ctrl-C to quit)
1) "subscribe"
2) "channel1"
3) (integer) 1
1) "subscribe"
2) "channel2"
3) (integer) 2
```

Run the code:

```
$ node index.js
[ 'channel2', 'channel1' ]
```

Node version:

```
$ node --version
v18.14.2
```